# mailto protocol not displaying percent encoded URL

Tags: html, vb.net, mailto

I have a link that will create an email with a link to the page the user is on.  This is a french site so there are some accented characters in the URL.  When the user clicks the link it opens the mail client and the email shows the link but it isn't percent encoded and a space is breaking the link instead of adding %20.

To get around the broken link part I just did this:

```
Dim SiteLink As String = ""
SiteLink = Replace(Current.Request.Url.ToString, " ", "%20")
SiteLink = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(SiteLink)
```

This is the URL I end up getting on the site, which looks correct:

```
<a href="mailto:?Subject=%20&body=Check%20out%20this%20page!%20%0dhttp%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A81%2Fadvancedwebpage.aspx%3FCategoryText1%3DRACCORDS%26CategoryText2%3DSYST%C3%88ME%2520CRIMPLOK%26SBCatPage%3D" class="CatSearch CatSearchAnchor">Envoyez Cette page courriel</a>
```

When the user clicks that link it opens an email and displays this:

Check out this page! [http://localhost:81/advancedwebpage.aspx?CategoryText1=RACCORDS&CategoryText2=SYSTÈME%20CRIMPLOK&SBCatPage=](http://localhost:81/advancedwebpage.aspx?CategoryText1=RACCORDS&CategoryText2=SYST%C3%88ME%20CRIMPLOK&SBCatPage=)

This is fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not in IE.  My question is how do I get the mail client to read the proper percent encoded URL?

Comment: Do you want us to check out your `localhost`? That's gonna be tricky...

Comment: @Badacadabra I don't want you to check out the link.  That link is just showing the accented character rather than the percent encoding